# @WithUserDetails failing because username not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to make a test for my `AuthController.java` but it keeps failing saying that the username is not found. I have narrowed this problem down to the line in `UserService.java` that checks if `foundUser == null`.

Here is my `AuthControllerTests.java`

```
package dev.tdwl.controller;

import dev.tdwl.repository.CategoryListsRepository;
import dev.tdwl.repository.UserRepository;
import dev.tdwl.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import dev.tdwl.services.UserService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {AuthController.class, UserService.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AuthControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @MockBean
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @MockBean
    private CategoryListsRepository categoryRepo;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails(value = "testuser", userDetailsServiceBeanName = "userService")
    void testAuthenticationCheckValid() {
        try {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/auth/check")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And my `AuthController.java`

```
package dev.tdwl.controller;


import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import dev.tdwl.model.AuthenticationRequest;
import dev.tdwl.model.CategoryLists;
import dev.tdwl.model.JwtResponse;
import dev.tdwl.model.User;
import dev.tdwl.repository.CategoryListsRepository;
import dev.tdwl.repository.UserRepository;
import dev.tdwl.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import dev.tdwl.services.UserDetailsImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Collections;

@RestController
public class AuthController {

    private CategoryListsRepository categoryRepo;
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(UserRepository repository, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, PasswordEncoder encoder, JwtUtils jwtUtils, CategoryListsRepository categoryRepo) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userRepo = repository;
        this.encoder = encoder;
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
        this.categoryRepo = categoryRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/auth/check")
    public ResponseEntity<?> verifyLogin() {
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (userDetails.getId() == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDetails);
    }

    @PostMapping("/auth/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getEmail(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, user.getUsername(), user.getId()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/auth/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateClient(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
        String email = authenticationRequest.getEmail();
        String password = authenticationRequest.getPassword();

        User newUser = new User(email, encoder.encode(password));

        try {
            userRepo.save(newUser);
            CategoryLists newList = new CategoryLists(newUser.getId(), Collections.emptyList());
            categoryRepo.save(newList);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException | MongoException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("User registered successfully!");
    }
}
```

and my `UserService.java`

```
package dev.tdwl.services;

import dev.tdwl.model.User;
import dev.tdwl.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User foundUser = userRepository.findUserByEmail(username);
        if (foundUser == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");

        return UserDetailsImpl.build(foundUser);
    }
}
```

The line this is failing on is in `UserService.java` where it tries to findUserByEmail, because userRepository is mocked it just returns null and throws the username not found exception. If I remove the Mock, then my test fails because it couldn't find the UserRepository bean required for the constructor in `AuthController`

Any ideas on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just by declaring Mockbean for UserRepository in this line:

```
@MockBean
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

It won't work. You need to add following piece of code before `mockMvc.perform()`.

```
Mockito.when(userRepository.findUserByEmail(Mockito.anyString)).thenReturn(new User());
```

This will mock the **findUserByEmail** method and it will not return null.